# Is it possible to somehow define create_thread in PyCord

Tags: python, discord, pycord

Hello I encountered the error **'Message' object has no attribute 'create_thread'**
Code:

```
@commands.command()
async def sugesstion(self, ctx, *,sugestia):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    embed = discord.Embed(colour = 0xFFA500) 
    embed.set_author(name=f' {ctx.message.author}', icon_url = f'{ctx.author.avatar_url}')
    embed.add_field(name = 'Member,', value = f'{sugestia}') 
    embed.set_footer(text="Apples")


    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed) 
    await msg.add_reaction('✔️') 
    await msg.add_reaction('➖')
    
    await msg.create_thread(name="Comments", auto_archive_duration=MAX)
```

Comment: @SandeepKanekal That would not change anything. @Loger Use [`await msg.channel.create_thread(message=msg, your_args=your_values)`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html#discord.TextChannel.create_thread)

Comment: Are you using Pycord 2.0?